# Choosing a web development framework?

Tags: web-development

So, I've sort of reached a point where I want to start developing a website. Originally, I planned to build said website using PHP and CodeIgniter, I'm familiar with both, but, truth be told, I'm not too fond of either. I find they just get rather messy, CodeIgniter helps somewhat, but no matter what, it seems that most PHP comes out more obfuscated than it has to be.

Anyways, I've come to the point where I want to either use Python or Ruby. I'm familiar in both, though more so towards Python, but I've never done any web development in them. I'll take the necessary time to learn the frameworks (and further my knowledge in the language of my choosing), but I need to choose one.

I don't like either language more than the other, they both have their benefits...

However, since I've never done any web development with either language, I was hoping that you guys could give me some pointers. What are the available frameworks for each language? What do you recommend and why?

Note: I've primarily looked into Rails and Django - but I'm still open to others. I'm looking for one that will work for just one (or maybe two) developers. It has to be fairly easy to learn (but I will take the time to learn it). Also, I'd like it to easily support clean code and agile development.

Comment: `PHP comes out more obfuscated than it has to be` -1 for blaming the tool for your inability to write clean code.

Comment: @YannisRizos the tool certainly doesn't help.

Comment: @YannisRizos Clearly you have't programmed in PHP, it's generally very complex and obfuscated - just by nature. I want something that innately produces clean code, not something powerful but broken.

Comment: @Raynos With that I'd agree, and expand that in some very specific cases not only doesn't it help, but it makes it impossible. But those cases are limited in the very high end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You answered it yourself: you prefer to code in Python and in Ruby rather than in PHP, and you are more familiar with Python out of the two.

So Python it is, and Django as the framework, as it's the most popular one (meaning you'll find more information/tutorials for it).

Comment: I would try web.py before Django.

Comment: Django is very well documented, which is a big plus for me.

Answer (score -1):

I think Ruby on Rails is your answer. It is designed for web applications. It supports clean code and agile development.